# why do we use signed and unsigned char datatype? Whats the purpose?

Tags: int, signed

Why do we use signed and unsigned char datatype?

A char can not be a +ve or -ve.
last bit is signed bit in accumulator.but not useful for `CHAR`
Whats the purpose? of doing it.

can we say char is nothing but coasted int ?

Answer (score 0):

While the `char` data type is commonly used to represent a character (and that's where it gets its name) it is also used when a very small amount of space, typically one byte, is needed to store a number. A signed char can store a number from -128 to 127, and an unsigned char can store a number from 0 to 255. When used to represent a character, however, you're correct that signed or unsigned is irrelevant.

By "coasted", I assume you meant to type "casted". `char` is not simply another type of `int`, as it can store a much smaller range of numbers. For instance, while an `int` can store the number 1,000, a `char` cannot.